# how do I get referrer information within my Android app

Tags: android, logging, referrer

I work for an e-commerce company that is heavily invested in the Android app. One of the things we try to measure if where some of our non marketing traffic comes to us from.

I've seen many resources that show you how to get the referrer information when an Android app is installed. But I haven't found any resource that tells me how to track the referrer information when the app is already installed and you want to see where the traffic came from. Here is my use case:

User A owns an Android device. For the purposes of this discussion, lets say its a Samsung Galaxy 6.
User has our company app installed. Lets name this app Krumblelina for the sake of this discussion.
User A is browsing Facebook (mobile web). User notices one of his friends has linked to our site. User A clicks on it.
The Samsung Galaxy 6 does not go through an interstitial page. It automatically detects that the app is installed. The Galaxy 6 automatically opens the app.
The action creates a new visit to our app. The referrer in this case is Facebook. However I do not know where to find that information.

We can apply the same example for User B. Except in this case, user B is browsing the Facebook App.

Any directionality in where to get this information would be appreciated. Thank you

Arsi

Comment: AFAIK, that information is not available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Sort of sucks if the majority of your traffic uses your app as opposed to your web/mobile web site.